# Is there an advantage to using WCF or WebAPI for mobile?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-web-api

I'm looking at doing my first mobile development using Mono Touch and Mono for Android.  I'd like them to communicate with an ASP.NET MVC 4 site I'm designing.  I've worked with WCF and WebAPI in the past but I'm wondering if there are any **quantifiable** advantages to using one over the other in this context?

Comment: Please just let WCF die.  Web api can do everything you need.

Comment: I'm not really sure that is fair to say, as Microsoft at a conference I just attended and one of there comments was to unify all the technologies.  So that the fractured fragmented nature that is present becomes irrelevant.  That way no one technology is not feasible or useable compared to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great article about that particular [topic](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341414/WCF-or-ASP-NET-Web-APIs-My-two-cents-on-the-subjec); hopefully this helps you out.

> Is there still use for WCF? when should I choose Web APIs over WCF?
>
> Recall my points from before - HTTP is a lot more than a transport
>   protocol; use SOAP across the board and consider HTTP as no more than
>   another way to pass messages.
>
> If your intention is to create services that support special scenarios
>   – one way messaging, message queues, duplex communication etc, then
>   you’re better of picking WCF
>
> If you want to create services that can use fast transport channels
>   when available, such as TCP, Named Pipes, or maybe even UDP (in WCF
>   4.5), and you also want to support HTTP when all other transports are unavailable, then you’re better off with WCF and using both SOAP-based
>   bindings and the WebHttp binding.
>
> If you want to create resource-oriented services over HTTP that can
>   use the full features of HTTP – define cache control for browsers,
>   versioning and concurrency using ETags, pass various content types
>   such as images, documents, HTML pages etc., use URI templates to
>   include Task URIs in your responses, then the new Web APIs are the
>   best choice for you.
>       If you want to create a multi-target service that can be used as both resource-oriented service over HTTP and as RPC-style SOAP service
>   over TCP